# Access token after authorize in Auth0

Tags: angularjs, auth0

Should I keep the token in the local store itself, or should I save it myself?

I call the method `angularAuth0.authorize()`;

Then in another controller I check the token using the `authService.isAuthenticated()` method and it constantly returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` ... ,a better way to share data between controllers is to use services 
 and to check authenticity, expired-token etc... you can use interceptors